# Strange behaviour with Apache mod_ratelimit

Tags: apache, apache2

I'm trying to use [mod_ratelimit](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_ratelimit.html), but it's exhibiting some odd behaviour.

Initially, my configuration was:

```
<Virtualhost>
...
<Directory /var/www/public>
    Order               Allow,Deny
    Allow from All

    Options       FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All

    SetOutputFilter RATE_LIMIT
    SetEnv rate-limit 250
</Directory>
...
</Virtualhost>
```

I've also tried:

```
<Virtualhost>
    ...
    SetOutputFilter RATE_LIMIT
    SetEnv rate-limit 250
    ...
</Virtualhost>
```

and

```
<Virtualhost>
<Location>
    ...
    SetOutputFilter RATE_LIMIT
    SetEnv rate-limit 250
    ...
</Location>
</Virtualhost>
```

I was expecting the 8 MB file I was downloading to take about 30 seconds. It was done in an instant.

I've tried several values for `rate-limit` and used wget to time them:

```
rate-limit | download speed
-----------+---------------
       250 | 440 MB/s
       100 | 440 MB/s
        50 | 440 MB/s
        30 |  20 kB/s
        25 |  20 kB/s
        10 |   6 kB/s
         1 | 500  B/s
```

This is apache 2.4 running on Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 1):

This may be a silly question, however, I ask because it has been missed before: Is the module enabled?

You can see this in /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/. By default, this module is not enabled.

From: https://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=Ubuntu_14.04&p=httpd2&f=7

```
root@www:~# a2enmod ratelimit 
root@www:~# vi /etc/apache2/conf-available/ratelimit.conf
# create new
# for example, limit bandwidth as 500 KB/sec under the /download location
<IfModule mod_ratelimit.c>
    <Location /download>
        SetOutputFilter RATE_LIMIT
        SetEnv rate-limit 500
    </Location>
</IfModule>
root@www:~# a2enconf ratelimit 
root@www:~# /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Another popular option is mod_dialup found at: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_dialup.html

Comment: Yes it's enabled

Comment: Hmm, I really don't want to cut all the way back to dial-up speeds... Just 1 MB/s, maybe, for testing

Comment: @HorusKol I have no experience with this module, however, you will see the example code is a bit different than what you have done. Even the 2.4 documentation you linked to in your question uses the Location directive. You will want to at least try using a Location directive or matching the example code above. Cheers!!

Comment: I've also tried that - it is the same result - and it should not matter if it's in a location or a directory. If you don't have experience, why are you answering?

Comment: @HorusKol You will notice that the code is set in the ratelimit.conf. I am not sure that is mandatory or even if ratelimit.conf is mandatory, but still worth a try. Why am I answering? Because all modules are basically the same and Apache is simple. I ask you, has anyone else answered? I do this to help people. I have been at it for 30 years and I am a retired systems internals engineer. I have been through the Apache code up until a few year ago and managed global Internet services on the scale of Google and Microsoft. The module works according to some. It is just a matter of time to solve.

Comment: The 2.5 documentation says it is valid to put the configuration in your Virtualhost (I have tried inside and outside of the Directory, and inside and outside of a Location) - the 2.4 documentation doesn't specify... also, if you look at my post, there is definitely an effect - just not what is expected.

Comment: @HorusKol There are two other things to make sure you try. You should be restarting Apache with each change. If you have not done this, you will need to. Also keep in mind that sometimes a restart does not recognize the change. This is rare, however, if this happens once, it will continue until you reboot. You may want to consider rebooting your system JIC. Lastly, check your log file, both access and error. Sometimes there are good clues that show up. Check the logs with each change.

Comment: Sorry if I somehow gave the impression that asking here was my first resort and that I had no idea how to do some basic investigation.

Comment: You have everything here. The answer is here. I have no impression that you are inexperienced. You came here for ideas. I am giving you ideas. If you do not appreciate it, you certainly do not have to be rude. That is no way to get help. We are professionals and there are some real experts here. I have been at this since the days I wrote router code for ARPA-Net which is the Internet today. Good luck. I am out.